# Angular ngbTypeahead doesn't reset value of input on blur

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using the bootstrap [ngbTypeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) of Angular2+ and I want to clean the input when lose focus and no item ware selected.

But the value doesn't clean when the typeahead shows options to select, even if I lose the input focus and dont select any item.

**Like This:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text"
        id="obj"
        formControlName="obj"
        class="form-control"
        [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed"
        [ngbTypeahead]="filter"
        (selectItem)="selectObj($event.item)"
        (blur)="blurObj()" />
```

**Typescript:**

```
filter = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    return text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => this.objSelected = null),
        switchMap( (term: string) => {
          if(term.length < 3) {            
            return [];
          } else {
            this.searching = true;
            return this.service.filter(term as string)
              .pipe(
                tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
                catchError(() => {
                    this.searchFailed = true;
                    this.searching = false;
                    return [];
                })
              );
          }
        }),
        tap(() => this.searching = false)
    );
}

selectObj(obj: any) {
    this.objSelected = obj;
}

blurObj() {
    if(!this.objSelected) {
      this.form.get('obj').setValue('');
    }
}
```

**This strange thing happens too:**

[image]

**Running Sample:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-spzwkm

**PS:** Type 3 or more characteres to test.

Comment: Update the ng-bootstrap

Comment: I can't do that

Comment: sorry, don't have time to check it now. it is possible that `editable='false'` would solve the problem

Comment: @IAfanasov No. That does not solve the problem and has no impact

Comment: I tried to investigate. seems like it is ng-bootstrap bug. `setTimeout(()=>this.form.get("obj").setValue(''), 1000)` helps, while `setTimeout(()=>this.form.get("obj").setValue(''), 100)` doesn't. Stopped on the fact that it is so old version of ng-bootstrap. I'm 100% sure you will encounter many more old bugs those are fixed in new version and same goes for accessibility. wish to luck on convincing your team to update the dependencies

Comment: I understand that it is an old version. But I cannot change it because it will have many impacts on other parts of the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that I used was override the function `dismissPopup()` of `NgbTypeahead`.

Like this:

```
import { NgbTypeahead } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

constructor(...) {
  NgbTypeahead.prototype.dismissPopup = function() {
    if (this.isPopupOpen()) {
      this._closePopup();
      if (this._elementRef.nativeElement.value !== '') {
        this._writeInputValue(this._inputValueBackup);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Running Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i8omg9